# how have access to datalist htmlanchor(href) control inside ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, controls, datalist

here the datalist with linkresponder like htmlanchor control

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataListComment" runat="server" DataKeyField="username" 
            EnableViewState="False" RepeatColumns="1">

        <ItemTemplate>

        <br />


    <a href='<%# Eval("commentid", "comment.aspx?commentid={0}") %>'
 runat="server" id="linkresponder" text='<%# Eval("commentname") %>'>



   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("commentdate") %>' />


</a>


   </ItemTemplate>



    </asp:DataList>
```

my try with no result

```
 foreach
                         (DataListItem item in DataListComment.Items)
                            {

                                HtmlAnchor link = item.FindControl("linkresponder") as HtmlAnchor;

                                link.Visible = false;



                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your anchor tag to an `asp:LinkButton` or `asp:HyperLink` control.